# Cassandra constraints

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

We have a usecase of allowing only certain values in a cassandra column.

Example:

```
 CREATED TABLE Cars(
    company text,
    model text,
    year int,
    vin text
 )
```

where a company may be from a spcific list of car makers e.g. GM, Toyota, Honda etc.

Does cassandra support defining constraints for above use-case ?
OR this needs to be handled at program level ?

Answer (score 4):

There is no in built support for enums in cassandra.

But Datastax drivers does have option to  define custom codec, which might help.

[Enum Java Driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/custom_codecs/extras/#enums)